# How to make an html page display the file instead of download it?

Tags: html, hyperlink, download, github-pages

I have a webpage hosted on github pages. On the page is a link to a .bib file. When I click the link to the bib file, it downloads the file. What I want is for it to open the bib file on my browser and display the content (it's just plain text). Is there a way to do this?

Here is a demo of what I want to happen: https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jcjohns/papers/iccv15/JohnsonICCV2015.bib When you click this link, it shows you the contents of the .bib file without downloading it. I want my website to do this as well.

My code:

`<a href="files/bib/filename.bib" ><b>[Bibtex]</b></a>`

The source code of the demo I linked above:

`<a href="papers/iccv15/JohnsonICCV2015.bib">[bib]</a>`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, there is a difference: the external link is a absolute url. Not a relative.

Comment: But on his website, it is just a link to the file in the same way as mine. That's what I was trying to show with the second line of source code `<a href="papers/iccv15/JohnsonICCV2015.bib">[bib]</a>`. Both his and my links to the bib file look the same in the html source. You can see this behavior yourself if you go to https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jcjohns/ and click the [bib] link for "Love Thy Neighbors: Image Annotation by Exploiting Image Metadata"

Answer (score 0):

In more recent browsers use an object Tag to display in the current browser window

```js
var Alink = document.getElementById('f100');
Alink.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    ShowFile();
}); 

function ShowFile(){
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var obj = document.createElement('object')

obj.setAttribute("data","https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jcjohns/papers/iccv15/JohnsonICCV2015.bib");
obj.setAttribute('width',300);
obj.setAttribute('height',100);


foo.appendChild(obj);
}
```

```html
<a href='#!' id='f100'>link 1</a>


<div id='foo'></div>
```

Here is a standard html if the server allows those files to be view-able...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <a href="https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jcjohns/papers/iccv15/JohnsonICCV2015.bib">[bib]</a>

        </body>
</html>

It works as well
```

Comment: So do something like `<object data="https://anonymous.github.io/files/bib/test.bib"><b>[bibtex]</b></object>` ? When I try this, it does not add a clickable link to take me to the file

Comment: No that would take you directly to the file ...<b>[bibtex]</b> would only display if the operation fails ... 

so you create separate file for the clicks ...  

<a href="textDisplay.html">[bib]</a>

Comment: Ill update my answer to create it pragmatically with JavaScript

Comment: What I don't understand is how this other person is able to do it (https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jcjohns/). If you scroll down to the paper titled "Love Thy Neighbors: Image Annotation by Exploiting Image Metadata" on his page and click the [bib] link under it, it takes you to a page that displays the .bib file contents without download it. Do you know how he was able to accomplish this?

Comment: Oh that is because his server is set up to make those files view able. 

copy and past from the second section my answer

Comment: So basically I can't get this behavior without using your suggested object tag since I don't have any way to change the server settings on github pages?

Comment: Yup I think github is Ruby and they would have to include bib in the mime file types on the ruby setup to behave like a text or html file